# Add button on polygon in svg

Tags: html, css, svg, responsive-design

I have svg as bottom, and I want to have a button on bottom line.

and be responsive.

What I want ti achieve is :

[image]

Is it possible with css and how can I achieve that?

```css
.container {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 500px;
  top: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}
svg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 0;
}
polygon {
  fill: green;
}
```

```html
 <div class="container">
 <svg viewBox="0 0 40 100" preserveAspectRatio="none">
  <polygon points="0,0 40,0 40,100 0,80" />
 </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Don't use position absolute if it should be responsive

Comment: I have added an answer.Please check.

Answer (score 0):

please check this answer:

codepen:- https://codepen.io/Rishab2019/pen/LYpzxKw

```css
.container {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 500px;
  top: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}

#t1{
  position:inherit;
  margin-top:-350px;
  color:white;
  font-size:40px;
  margin-left:400px;
}
#t2{
  
  margin-top:0px;
  color:white;
  font-size:40px;
  margin-left:400px;
}

#t3{
  
  margin-top:0px;
  color:white;
  font-size:40px;
  margin-left:400px;
}

#t4{
  
  margin-top:-125px;
  margin-bottom:0px;
  color:white;
  font-size:35px;
  margin-left:700px;
}

#t5{
  
  margin-top:0px;
  color:white;
  font-size:35px;
  margin-left:700px;
}
#t6{
  
  margin-top:0px;
  color:white;
  font-size:35px;
  margin-left:700px;
}
svg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 0;
}
polygon {
  fill: green;
}

.mybutton{
  color:white;
  background-color:#e6c619;
  border:none;
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
  justify-content:center;
  border-radius:20px;
  width:160px;
  height:40px;
  margin-left:30%;
  margin-top:405px;
  cursor:pointer;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 0px grey;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 0px grey;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 0px grey;
}



@media all and (max-width:768px){
  
  .mybutton{
    width:140px;
    margin-top:411px;
    
  }
  
}


@media all and (min-width:620px) and (max-width:940px){
#t1{
  position:relative;
  margin-top:-350px;
  color:white;
  font-size:40px;
  margin-left:20.7%;
}
#t2{
  
  margin-top:0px;
  color:white;
  font-size:40px;
  margin-left:20.7%;
}

#t3{
  
  margin-top:0px;
  color:white;
  font-size:40px;
  margin-left:20.7%;
}
  
  #t4{
  
  margin-top:-125px;
  margin-bottom:0px;
  color:white;
  font-size:35px;
  margin-left:57.3%;
}

#t5{
  
  margin-top:0px;
  color:white;
  font-size:35px;
  margin-left:57.3%;
}
#t6{
  
  margin-top:0px;
  color:white;
  font-size:35px;
  margin-left:57.3%;
}
  
}


@media all and (max-width:619px){
#t1{
  margin-top:-350px;
  color:white;
  font-size:40px;
  margin-left:50px;
}
#t2{
  
  margin-top:0px;
  color:white;
  font-size:40px;
  margin-left:50px;
}

#t3{
  
  margin-top:0px;
  color:white;
  font-size:40px;
  margin-left:50px;
}
  
  #t4{
  
  margin-top:-125px;
  margin-bottom:0px;
  color:white;
  font-size:35px;
  margin-left:57.3%;
}

#t5{
  
  margin-top:0px;
  color:white;
  font-size:35px;
  margin-left:57.3%;
}
#t6{
  
  margin-top:0px;
  color:white;
  font-size:35px;
  margin-left:57.3%;
}
  
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

 <svg viewBox="0 0 40 100" preserveAspectRatio="none">
  <polygon points="0,0 40,0 40,100 0,80" />
    </svg>

</div>
<button class="mybutton">LOGIN</button>
  <div id="t1">Some Text</div>
  <div id="t2">Some Text</div>
  <div id="t3">Some Text</div>
  <div id="t4">Some Text</div>
  <div id="t5">Some Text</div>
  <div id="t6">Some Text</div>
```

and it's responsive.

Comment: In my case it is not responsive, because I have some text on the container and this `svg` is work as background image and I want to add this button that line.

Comment: I add new image.

Comment: This is not responsive, because as texts become longer.

Comment: you can make it small using @media queries.That means, when you reduce screen , size, the font size also reduces.

Comment: My problem is with margins you add. I don't think is a good way.

Comment: that will not effect the page in a bad way.When you reduce browser size, margins will auto adjust

Comment: I know but as I said `Some Text` are longer so they come on each other. I think best solution is using flexbox and my exact problem is on adding button to that position.

Comment: As I said when text grow up the svg height will grow to, so margin not work for responsive.